# nav fill bar on hover, please check

Tags: css, navigation, hover

I want my nav items to fill the bar on hovering
Pasted HTML in there aswell, so you can have a better look on it.

http://i43.tinypic.com/309mzkn.png

The black is on hovering it, how i make it fill the green bar nicely.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="headerMenu">
  <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Find friends online."/> </a>
      </div>

      <div class="search_box">
        <form method="get" action="search.php" id="search">
      <input name="q" type="text" size="60" placeholder="Search for people or places near you..." />
        </form>
      </div>
       <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="homepageSignup">
        <section id="signup">
        <h2>Sign up Below...</h2>
        <form action="#" method="post">
        <input type="text" size="25" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" size="25" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" size="25" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Sign Up">
        </form>
  </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    #menu {
        position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;
        margin-right:6%;
        height:38px;
    }
    #menu ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #menu ul li {
        float:left;
        margin-right:15px;
    }
    #menu ul li a {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size:18px;
        color:#fff;
    }
    #menu ul li a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size:18px;
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#000;
        -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 800ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 800ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 800ms ease;
        transition: all 800ms ease;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to fill the entire green area with black when you hover over an option or just fill the area around the option?

Comment: Can you post HTML along with it? If JS is allowed, you can change the background of what I assume to be an container for #menu

Comment: @JHuangweb i posted the Html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not actually sure why your black section is floating in the middle. You have a padding on the parent of the list?

In any case. Remove any padding on the parent of the list. And make the list element anchors be the same height as your bar.

So something like this

```
#menu
{
    height:38px;
    margin-right:6%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
#menu
{
    display: block;
}
#menu li
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#menu li a
{
    height:38px;
}
#menu li a:hover
{
    background: #000000;
}
```

This is rough. If you post a jsfiddle or actual code I will revise my post appropriately.

Comment: So I updated your fiddle. It should be something like what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/33BhC/2/. Anyways, I generally prefer using display: inline-block on elements like lists when you want them to display horizontally, means you don't have to play with using clear: both on elements to get elements to render properly, however it has its other caveats.

Comment: Found a fix with

#menu {
position: absolute;
top: -12px;
right: 0px;
margin-right: 6%;
display: block;
height: 38px;
}

but that's not really a good way is it?

Comment: I cannot do much to help you in this instance unless you post the full css stylesheet. It could have something to do with margin or padding on your wrapper. Or vertical alignment on your ul.

No that's not really a good way.

Comment: Your ul is inheriting a top and bottom margin of 12px from the default styling. Typically to resolve this issue people employ a "css reset". I generally use this one. Be warned, this could mess with how your styling currently appears, it should be placed before any styling you apply. Using a css reset will mitigate further issues like this down the line. I would suggest you use a css reset, and fix any problems that occur, and remove the top: -12px;

Comment: Instead of that , i added margin-top:0px and margin-bottom:0px; and works aswell :D thanks

Comment: That would work too, I would like to point out for best practices, you should probably use a css reset. However I'm glad you've resolved your issue, could you please mark this answer as correct?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it was an accepted answer and it looks like a good deal of effort went into solving the problem... Have a +1 to bring you back to even...

Answer (score -1):

Without your actual HTML markup, this is just a guess but you should be able to change

`#menu ul li a:hover {`

to

`#menu ul li:hover {`

in order to achieve what you want. Or, you could add padding to the `a` elements to compensate. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/tmQ8T/

Comment: OP is asking to change fill the entire "green bar", thus we need to see the markup of the green bar and use JS to update its background color.

Comment: Generally you would want the padding or height of the element in the <a> so that the blank space is clickable. You mentioned it but I thought I would clarify for anyone who reads this.

Comment: @jhuangweb yeah, I wasn't exactly sure what OP was asking for. I asked in a comment, but figured I'd leave one of the possible solutions since we still haven't had any confirmation from OP

Comment: @jamesmcdonnell Good point, thanks for expanding on the padding.